# read a text file in jupyter notebook: UnicodeDecodeError: codec can't decode byte xx

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, unicode

my code is so simple. in handling string on python i don't know the unicode thing. sad.

```
f = open("~161209.txt", "r")
f.read()
```

I don't know how to fix this
error code is below:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'cp949' codec can't decode byte 0xec in position 121: illegal multibyte sequence
```

Comment: have you tried: `f = open("~161209.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8")` ?

Comment: it works....it is so easy.....thank you all your help. thank you

Comment: I couldn't not find a suitable duplicate for that one, hence my edit to the question to improve the title and my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python 3 provides encoding support directly through `open`:

```
f = open("~161209.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8")
```

For older versions, you have to use the `codecs` module or `io.open` function.